# Using a Parameterized column in a Where Clause using Case

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, where-clause, ssrs-2012

I am building a report in SSRS where I need to be able to let our users filter on different date fields. They need to be able to select the date filter and then the start and end dates within that filter.

This is a simplified Example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
SELECT Project.ProjectID, Project.Name, Project.Update_Date, Project.Due_Date, Project.Start_Date, Project.Review_Date
FROM Project
WHERE @datetypefiler BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
```

Where the @datetypefiler will essentially equal the field the user wishes to filter on (i.e. Project.Update_Date or Project.Due_Date etc)

On SSRS i built parameters for @datetypefiler which could equal the various date fields and I set up the start date and end date filter as expected.

Unfortunately it does not seem as though I can parameterize the @datetypefiler in this way? I then attempted to use the Case keyword as so:

```
SELECT Project.ProjectID, Project.Name, Project.Update_Date, Project.Due_Date, Project.Start_Date, Project.Review_Date
FROM Project
WHERE CASE 
when @datetypefiler='Project.Update_Date' then Project.Update_Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
when @datetypefiler='Project.Due_Date' then Project.Due_Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
```

This isnt working for me either, I figure that instead of taking shots in the dark I should ask what the correct method would look like. Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could try this

```
SELECT Project.ProjectID, Project.Name, Project.Update_Date, Project.Due_Date, 
Project.Start_Date, Project.Review_Date 
FROM Project
where 
(CASE 
when @datetypefiler = 'Project.Update_Date' then Project.Update_Date 
when @datetypefiler= 'Project.Due_Date' then Project.Due_Date 
END) BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Project
WHERE  (@datetypefiler='Project.Update_Date' 
                    AND Project.Update_Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)
    OR (@datetypefiler='Project.Due_Date' 
                    AND Project.Due_Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)
```

The `OR` will only evaluate the full statement if the `@datetypefiler` is matched.

Comment: Hey thanks for the advice! Rex's solution is the first one I tried as it is slightly cleaner in that the start and End date are handled once but in theory it is exactly the same as yours and you posted first. Credit to both you and Rex for helping me out, its very appreciated!

Comment: @sqlquery123 It might be worth checking the execution plan for both mine and the accepted solution if performance is a concern.

Answer (score 0):

While both of other two answers are going to work just fine, they won't make use of index. I'd recommend to have two separate `SELECT` statements with two different queries based on your criteria, this way you can index your table both on `Update_Date` and `Due_Date` and actually use them to speed your queries up.

Comment: Why wouldn't the later one make use of indexes?

Comment: Or condition for two different columns. Try it yourself

Comment: I thought that was mainly a MySQL limitation that MS SQL Server doesn't suffer from.

Comment: I wish it didn't... 